# Can we run pylint while executing python script, such that when the pylint passes the code will execute else it will show pylint errors?

Tags: python

example : lets say I have a python script **test.py**
so when I run the script **python test.py** pylint should execute first and If pylint executes successfully It should execute **tesy.py** else should give pylint errors

Comment: `pylint test.py && python test.py`

Comment: You can run first thing in script os.system("pylint test.py > bla") and check bla file. You you happy with result, continue excution, else return what bla contains.

Comment: @falsetru : This is fine but is there any way where in we run **python test.py** and **pylint** also gets executed.

Comment: @RohanNagalkar, Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@falsetru : Thank you for the answer, another solution is that we can write a script in which we will run both the commands ie. **pylint test.py** and if the rate of the code(output of the pylint) is greater than **x**(lets say x = 8) will run **python test.py** else show the pylint errors.

ie instead of **python test.py** we will run **my_script test.py**

**my_script** is the script which contains the above mentioned code.